# LDO powered by a half-bridge rectifier connected to 9 VAC ripples when under load

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, rectifier, voltage-measurement

I've been working on the a breakout board or the Pi Pico to measure voltage and current as well as turn on and off two relays.

I've been basing it off of OpenEnergyMonitor's [emontx3](https://github.com/openenergymonitor/emontx3) and they [suggested](https://learn.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/voltage-sensing/why-cant-i-use-a-single-transformer) using a half-bridge rectifier as it allows for voltage sampling and power delivery on an single 9 VAC [transformer](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ideal-power-ltd/77DA-12-09/15667498?s=N4IgTCBcDaICIEEC0BGMSAMBOEBdAvkA).

This is the circuit I initially made:

[image: voltage sensing and power circuit]

To allow for more current draw to power the relays I swapped out the LDO for the [NCV5501DT50RKG](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp5500-d.pdf) that has a maximum 500 mA output current.

When I went to test it for the first time the Pico continuously restarted itself. I assume that this may have to do with C5 not being a polarized capacitor, so I removed it and replaced it with a 47 μF polarized cap. This was able to power just the Pico but as soon as a relay was turned on the LDO kept turning on an off again.

I changed it to a 470 μF cap, it was audibly noticeable (with the relay) that it took longer to shut off. I'm guessing this is because it took more time to discharge it as the 470 μF cap stores more energy.

Using my voltmeter when C5 is a 470 μF cap, the input voltage drops from 9.36 V to 2.40 V when the relay is powered on and the output drops from 5.06 V to 2.34 V. When C5 is 47 μF, the input voltage drops from 7.91 V to 6.9 V when the relay is powered on and the output drops from 5.04 V to 4.7 V.

Measuring the current at the AC side for both setups was around 70 mA. I've also powered trough the LDO with a variable DC supply at 9 V which works and it says it draws 99 mA.

I'm out of ideas. I think I'm going to attach leads to the Vin and GND so I can test how many caps it takes for this to work. Is there any better practice in selecting a capacitor to remove the ripple voltage?

Comment: Where is your 9 VAC connected, J6? If yes, you are half-wave rectifying the voltage so you need a gigantic capacitor for hold-up.

Comment: Yes the 9VAC is connected to J6. I see why you need a larger cap is there any way to reduce the required capacitance?

Comment: DC power supply instead of AC or a full wave rectifier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regulator may be capable of 500 mA, but at that current you would have a voltage drop across the 56 \$\Omega\$ resistor of 28 V.

You would either need to reduce the value of that resistor by around a factor of 10, or eliminate it completely. You should also probably put a filter cap right at the rectifier.

You can calculate how much resistance you can use there by taking the rectified voltage and subtracting the regulated voltage plus the regulator dropout voltage, and dividing by the maximum current.
For example with a minimum of 9 V at the rectifier (remember the output of a half wave rectifier is going to have a lot of ripple so take that into account), 5.5 V for the regulator and output, and 500 mA max current you would have

$$ \frac{3.5 V}{500 mA} = 7 \Omega$$

Giving it a bit of margin for error you'd probably want 5.6\$\Omega\$ or less.

Comment: Thanks I removed the 56 ohm resistor shorted it, It worked with the 470 uF capacitor. I guess you have a resistor there for a surge limit?

Comment: @MatthewElphinstone Your linear regulator will most probably self-limit to survive any such event. No need for a resistor in series. Any particular reason you don’t use a full wave rectifier?

Comment: @MatthewElphinstone I think they may have been using it as a low pass filter with C5 so they could use a lower value capacitor. Probably works okay if you don't need more than a few 10s of mA.